# Tomcat Context Root - Tiles Exception when deploy a Spring app to Tomcat

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, tiles

I have a Spring MVC 4 application deployed in tomcat. It works fine. I have to clone this app to have several applications with same behaviour but different configurations: database instance and folders for file management. Each for different customers. When I deploy de original application to Linux Tomcat it works fine (https://hostname:8443/app1).

Then I change the db connection settings (database name, username, and folders to manage some generated files) and change the name of the artefact to customername. But when I get into the application, it shows the login page right, but when login into the app, I'm getting the following error:

```
Status HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: java.io.IOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/layout/header.jsp'

javax.servlet.ServletException: File [/WEB-INF/layout/header.jsp] not found
```

when accessing to https://hostname:8443/customername, which it's part of tiles template. Files exist in the deployed application, It's able to reach the login page, so it seems to be resolved the tiles config, but I don't know why is not able to reach the jsp files. It's working fine in local windows without secure Tomcat (port 8080).

**EDITED**

If I change the name of customername.war to app1.war it's working fine. Anybody knows where the war file keep a reference to the base application app1? It seems that there a reference to app1 in somewhere that makes that If I change the application name (artifact id) it does not reference to customername path.

Seems that it's a context root issue. I have changed it in STS (Project > Properties > Web Project Settings > Context root), deployed on Tomcat but still not working. It's supposed that only with changing the war file name, the context root of the application should be updated, but it's not working.

Comment: That's urgent for us. ;-)

Comment: Maybe your structure configured for  "https://hostname:8443/"

Comment: No, if I change the app name to original app1 name, it deploys app1 web app and the same web app works fine with context root app1, but not if change to customername

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Tomcat from 8.0 to 8.5.5 solves the issue. I don't know why, but there's an issue in 8.0 because no way to force context root for an application, not context.xml application file neither other configuration.

Just upgrade to 8.5.5 and deploy applications without context issue.

BR